# ASPNET MVC App returns different status codes through Ajax and Fetch

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vue.js, authorization

recently ran in to a bug that seems to be caused by the `Authorize` attribute on MVC controllers in a ASP.NET app. When the session token for the user has expired we noticed that we run in to two different status codes. Ajax gives us a 402 when it fails and Fetch gives us a 302. What would be the reason behind this? There are two separate pages where one was doing everything in it with Ajax and the other was using Fetch for everything. Is this caused from the controller or from the the front end (MVC View pages with Vue 2 JS in them).

Additionally there are plans to move away from using MVC and instead have a full Vue3 front end. Would this issue still occur between Fetch and Axios or would that not be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

When I worked with MVC and Vue2 a couple years ago we ran into this same problem; we found that fetch ignores all 401s ever sent and overwrites them to be 302. For this reason, we changed all of our fetch calls to ajax in order to produce more consistent and performative applications.